# The given role or permission should use guard `` instead of `web`. -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I am using a package spatie for user roles and permission. When creating and assigning a role to user, i get the error

> > The given role or permission should use guard `` instead of `web`

Below is how i save my data in the controller

What could be causing this issue in my application ?

**Controller**

```
  $user = new User;
        $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->login = Input::get('login');
        $user->desc = Input::get('desc');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        // $user->group = Input::get('group');
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();
        $user->assignRole(Input::get('roles'));
```

**config/auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should check if in your model there is

```
protected $guard_name = 'web';
```

You need to specify the guard name in each model you use the role manager.

Since the roles are related to the guard you can't apply a role to a user with different guard

check the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards)

Comment: Saved my day! Without this attribute, spatie cannot allow controllers on __constructor using middleware.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue and it was because of typo in users model in `config/auth.php`.
Also check your User class namespace.

Laravel model's guard is 'web' by default. You don't need to change it.

```sh
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],
```

Comment: Doh, I also adopt the models folder structure and had forgotten to update. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function guardName(){
        return "web";
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I moved my `User` model to another folder, as I checked the `auth.php` file I noticed the pointer to `User` model is wrong so I changed it to the correct path and the problem solved.

**Lravel default config file for auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

**after I changed it to the correct path**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Domain\User\Models\User::class, // just change it to the path, which your `User` model exists
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 8 or laravel lemun
past this code in config/auth.php

```
    <?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\User::class
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'api', 'guard' key array or whatever you want in guards array key on file config/auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

[image]